# PHP encode string plus current date

Tags: php, string, date, encode

I can't figure out how to encode a string + current hour in a somewhat shortish garbled result... something like:

```
$random = base64_encode($_POST['phone']);
```

with a date appended to the phone var that's also encoded, when I do the above it comes out to a long garbled mess, I'd like it to be somewhat shorter. Is there a way to do this that I'm missing ?

Comment: What on earth are you trying to accomplish? That "garbled mess" is the result of `base64_encode()`.

Comment: I know, that's what I want, but a shorter result.

Comment: #1 question: Why? Are you decoding this at some point? Why do you care about the length of the string? If you double encode you will have to double decode as well and you'll lose the ability to separate the two pieces of data. What are you doing with this string? Also: What does `$random` mean here, because the results are certainly not random.

Comment: Do you just want a random string at a specified length? I really can't make heads or tails of this.

Comment: random was a bad name for it, I know its not random, I just want it to appear like a random string after it's encoded, I DO take that seemingly random string and check it against something else in the code... I'm sure this is bad practice but I really just want a way to do what I was accomplishing above but make the result shorter, if thats possible. Possibly something else then base64_encode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer your question literally, since I can't get any insight into your actual use case or what your real goals are.

---

> I can't figure out how to encode a string + current hour

```
$string = base64_encode('some string' . date('H'));
```

---

> something like: `$random = base64_encode($_POST['phone']);` with a date appended to the phone var that's also encoded

```
$string = base64_encode($_POST['phone'] . base64_encode(date('H')));
```

---

> when I do the above it comes out to a long garbled mess, I'd like it to be somewhat shorter. Is there a way to do this that I'm missing ?

```
$my_string_length = 100;
$string = substr($string, 0, $my_string_length);
```

---

Just keep in mind that this is not truly a random string, and that you'll be encoding your data into a form that will prevent you from picking apart the two separate pieces of data.